# Why is the Visual C++ Redistributable Package Required?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

If the code compiled by a visual C++ compiler is straight C++, why do you need a redistributable package? Does this make your code platform dependant? Does using the visual C++ compiler with the redistributable package provide any advantage over using another IDE along with g++?

Comment: Compiled code is *always* platform dependent. It works on, and only on, the platform it was compiled for.

Comment: It isn't required.  You should create a Setup project instead.  Or compile with /MT instead of /MD so you don't need it at all.  Risky however when you use DLLs.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The code is not platform dependent, the **resulting executable** is. It is linked against the MS libraries with the standard library implementation, that are included in the redistributable as DLL's.

IIRC there should be an option for static linking of everything, so that you wouldn't need the additional redistributable, but the resulting binary would still be platform dependent - for example you can't run a windows binary on a UNIX system (without WINE at least).

Comment: You have a choice to include the memory manager, standard I/O library, and such as a separate copy in every single application, with no good way to manage it and upgrade it and tons of bloat, or to install a single run-time that contains all that code once for every application that might need it.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz yeah... And I think that its included by default with all the Windows installations anyway, is it right?

Comment: It depends which Windows installation and which run time. A new installation of Windows Vista SP1, for example (if anyone still installs that) won't have the VS2010 runtime.

Comment: Even a fresh installation of Windows Server 2008 R2 doesn't have the VS 2010 runtime installed, or at least I don't recall that it does... These are intended to be redistributed. But note that it is still possible to create an executable with Microsoft's C/C++ compiler that is *not* linked upon the C runtime libraries, and therefore is not dependent upon their being installed.

Comment: @littleadv I don't think it is. Of course, I can't confirm this because I do not own a machine that doesn't already have VS on it. I do know that in most linux distros however, the header files for c are not included until you install gcc and both the header files and many of the libs (depending on the distro) are not installed for c++ until you install g++. Unless, the header files for the c and c++ stdlibs are precompiled, I can't imagine that they come with the Windows OS. However, I don't know how the Windows OS runs without the libs as much of it is written in c++.

Comment: So in your opinions, does VC++ provide any advantage over compilation with another IDE with g++?

Comment: No, there's no advantage. Any decent C++ compiler is just fine, and both Microsoft's and G++ qualify a "decent". There is some talk among those who talk about such things that Microsoft's compiler produces better Windows code than G++ (that is, it is better at optimizing/tweaking code for Windows applications), but I'm not sure that there is any truth to such claims. You'd have to profile it and see for yourself. Any difference, however, is likely to be extremely minor and almost insignificant. If you're already content with G++, then just stick with it. And if you like VC++, likewise.

Answer (score 6):

There is no such thing as "Straight C++". There will always be some library functions that you are calling here and there in your code, and even if you are very careful not to, there will be some functions that will need to be called simply by code emitted by the compiler. For example if you have the following loop:

```
for( int i = 0;  i < count;  i++ )
    array1[i] = array2[i];
```

The compiler will replace it with code which simply copies the memory over. And if you are compiling for smaller size instead of speed, this will be a call to a function very much like memmove().

Also, you may have some floating point operations for which there exist no direct x86 equivalent instructions; these will also be implemented with function calls. And the list goes on.

This does not make your code platform dependant, because on a different platform the compiler of that plafrom will compile the same code of yours to go with whatever is the C++ runtime for that platform.

Luckily, the C++ runtime does not have to be a separate entity from your application. Check your compiler and linker options; you should be able to produce a single executable which contains both.  If you have found that g++ does not require a separate runtime, it is because it does exactly that by default.

Answer (score 1):

The C++ redistributable are specific to the IDE that you are using ("IDE" I say, but that's really specific to the compiler, yet the IDE & compiler are both being assigned new versions as things move along.)

It is made specific to that IDE, but not to the Win OS. So it should be backward compatible (assuming you're not using new APIs, obviously.) Actually, this is done so it is backward compatible (and not the other way around as you're thinking.) This allows you to use the latest greatest IDE version (10, 11, 12...) and still run your code on Win2k!

Now, of course, it's much different from Linux where you're expected to recompile on each main version anyway. Most Unix systems will work that way.

I do not know of a way to compile C++ statically so as to be able to avoid those redistributables. It may be possible, although it would certainly make your .exe very big.

Answer (score 0):

I always keep a copy of Visual C++ 6 installed on a xp Virtual Machine (Wont work properly in Win 6/7/8). Sometimes I write or am asked to write an utility app for doing something fast and/or once off that I compile as a single exe. I got sick of sending a simple program written using only the std lib to someone else only for them to tell me that it doesn't work because of some missing dll or re-distributable pack.

Answer (score 0):

In your Project Properties, C/C++, Code Generation set Runtime library to /MT for your release build.

(Credits to Mike Danes who answered this question on social.msdn: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/09afd4be-7a15-4772-98c1-a0464a96cd7f/how-to-static-linkage-in-visual-c-express-edition-2010?forum=vcgeneral&prof=required)