# Error: "DLL functions could not be loaded!"

Tags: c++, visual-studio, mfc

I created a MFC application in my **desktop** using Visual Studio. The debug and build of this MFC application in my **desktop** work well.

But when I debug and build the application in my **notebook**, when debug using Local Windows Debugger, always get error prompt:

```
Error: "DLL functions could not be loaded!"
```

Press [OK] button on the prompt window, the application starts, but another error prompt pop up.

```
An error ocurred. Error-code's text (10000h) couldn't be retrieved
```

I am not quite familiar with Visual Studio, I try to find which DLL cause the issue, but could not find in the logs.

Can you give some ideas? Is there a way for checking which DLL causes the issue?

Comment: You need to learn dealing with VS C++ Redistributable packages.

Comment: Can your program start on the notebook?

Comment: @prehistoricpenguin Yes. but another error pops up.

Comment: It's better to describe the error in detail. Have you installed `Visual Studio` on your notebook? MFC is not worth learning nowadays :).

Comment: Could you attach more screenshot about error or any other things like projects properties or DLL paths? I think may be this wrong DLL paths (which using static DLL path instead of using dynamic DLL path) or like @SM mentioned VC++ Redistributable packages. More details about VC++ RP: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8708075/why-is-the-visual-c-redistributable-package-required

Comment: Neither error message is one I remember having seen before. Is this a standard MFC application, or has this been customized?

Comment: Thanks for all your reply. I find the issue is caused by one of my DLLs is out of date. After I replace with new DLL, it works.

Answer (score -2):

Try using windeployqt.exe.

1. Open the Qt Terminal of your compiler
2. Go to the project's directory
3. Run the following command: windeployqt.exe .

- This dot at the end of the command is important

Comment: There is no Qt involved here.